# How to convert mouse input to mobile touch in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to game development. I am trying to make something like rising up. I tried to change the flowing code to make workable for mobile touchscreen unfortunately failed. can you help me how can I make flowing code for mobile?

```
private Vector2 mousePos;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

private Vector2 offsetClicked;
private Vector2 offsetReleased;

private void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    offsetReleased = transform.position;
}

private void FixedUpdate () {
    mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        Vector2 newPos = new Vector2 (
            Mathf.Clamp(mousePos.x + offsetClicked.x, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.w + 0.32f, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.y - 0.32f),
            mousePos.y + offsetClicked.y
        );

        rb.MovePosition (newPos);
        offsetReleased = newPos - (Vector2) Camera.main.transform.position;
    } //Clicked
    else {
        Vector2 newPos = new Vector2 (
            Mathf.Clamp (Camera.main.transform.position.x + offsetReleased.x, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.w + 0.32f, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.y - 0.32f),
            Camera.main.transform.position.y + offsetReleased.y
        );

        rb.MovePosition (newPos);
        offsetClicked = newPos - mousePos;
    } //Released
}
```

Above code working for mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the mouse button was clicked, check if any touches exist, then extract the touch position. `Input.touches` returns a list of the touches during the last frame, so you can use that to find the position of the touch that will replace `mousePos` in your code.

```
Touch myTouch;
Vector2 myTouchPosition;

Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        myTouch = Input.touches[0]; //Get the first touch
        myTouchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(myTouch.position);
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can use the [touch phases](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html) to determine at which point during a touch you want something to occur.

Comment: i tried but it's not workable .would you try on my full code

Comment: Sure. Could you help me understand what didn't work though? Did it compile but not behave as expected?

Comment: it compile but not behave as expected

Comment: what  I did to make workable?. https://gist.github.com/nazmulkp/37f13af7b29324ebd2211e4423c417fc

Comment: The code I posted above was only meant to be a sample of how to get the position of a touch. In your code you don't need to add an Update function, just add `myTouch = Input.touches[0];` and `mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(myTouch.position);` to your fixed update function right after the if statement where you check if any touches exist.

Answer (score 0):

Import in the `CrossPlatformInput` package into your project and you could actually continue to use Input.GetMouseButton(xxx).

```
using UnityEngine;
using CrossPlatformInput;

    public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector2 mousePos;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private Vector2 offsetClicked;
    private Vector2 offsetReleased;

    private void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        offsetReleased = transform.position;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate () {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            Vector2 newPos = new Vector2 (
                Mathf.Clamp(mousePos.x + offsetClicked.x, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.w + 0.32f, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.y - 0.32f),
                mousePos.y + offsetClicked.y
            );

            rb.MovePosition (newPos);
            offsetReleased = newPos - (Vector2) Camera.main.transform.position;
        } //Clicked
        else {
            Vector2 newPos = new Vector2 (
                Mathf.Clamp (Camera.main.transform.position.x + offsetReleased.x, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.w + 0.32f, GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.y - 0.32f),
                Camera.main.transform.position.y + offsetReleased.y
            );

            rb.MovePosition (newPos);
            offsetClicked = newPos - mousePos;
        } //Released
    }

}
```

(see here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CrossPlatformConsiderations.html )

> **Touches and clicks**
>
> The Input.GetMouseButtonXXX functions are designed so that they have a
>   reasonably obvious interpretation on mobile devices even though there
>   is no “mouse” as such. A single touch on the screen is reported as a
>   left click and the Input.mousePosition property gives the position of
>   the touch as long as the finger is touching the screen. This means
>   that games with simple mouse interaction can often work transparently
>   between the desktop and mobile platforms. Naturally, though, the
>   conversion is often much less straightforward than this. A desktop
>   game can make use of more than one mouse button and a mobile game can
>   detect multiple touches on the screen at a time.

Comment: it's not working perfectly. once I touch the screen player position automatic move right top corner. and not smooth.

Comment: It's probably related to what you are doing here: 

`GameManager.gm.cameraEdges.w + 0.32f`